# How to find the Key/Value classes of a Hashmap (Java)

Tags: java, generics, hashmap

If you were given a generic HashMap, how would you find the class of it's keys and values?
I have a method whose Definition is:

`public <K, V> Map<K, V> getMap(final String name, Class<K> keyClass, Class<V> valueClass)`

This method has access to a collection of generic maps whose keys and values can be any object type, and it returns the one with the same name(how isn't important) and the same types of classes. I tried two methods:
1.
Making an iterator over the map I'm going to return, and checking the entry's `getKey().getClass()` and `getValue().getClass()` Which works except for when the map is empty, and edge cases like that are a total no go.

2. Trying to make a new `Map<K,V> map = the map I'm checking it against`, and then i would try to catch the ClassCastException, but that wasn't ever being thrown. My guess is that this is the better approach but I am missing something.

Any help would be much appreciated, Generics are not my best subject in Java

Comment: Generics are a compile-time feature and, in general, runtime types will not record actual type arguments. Typically you want to avoid forgetting static types if you are going to need them later. Retaining your API, you might want to make all three of the method's parameters into a key (`MyKey`) for use in a `Map<MyKey,Map<?,?>>`.

Comment: I see, that is much smarter and easier to implement, thank you!

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline I suggest making an Answer of your Comment so this Question can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

As Tom Hawtin said, the best way to solve a runtime type problem like this is to keep track of it from earlier. Instead of trying to find the class(es) of a generic later, keep track of what generic you used and it's type, probably in a Map